# Limit UITextView to only 2 lines

Tags: ios, uitextview, limit, lines

I searched the web but could not find an acceptable solution to my problem. So, basically I have a UITextView in my project and I want the user to only be able to put in 2 lines of text. If the text has reached the 2 lines than it should not let the user put in anything more. (Exactly like in Snapchat but with 2 lines instead of one). I have some code which basically does what I want but instead of stopping the user from putting in more text it just puts periods to the end of the text.

```
self.textView.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2;
self.textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
```

I thought that maybe there is an option to achieve this in the NSLineBreakBy object but unfortunately there is not.

Any ideas on how could I do this?

Comment: So, you'd get more text on some devices that others, depending on the size?

Answer (score 1):

> If the text has reached the 2 lines than it should not let the user put in anything more.

You could implement the delegate method `textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` such that you don't allow a return if the text already has two lines.